# Issues when using f2py module in python code

Tags: python, compilation, fortran, compiler-flags, f2py

I have a FORTRAN code that required the following compile command

```
gfortran -c interp.f -ffixed-format -ffix-line-length-none
```

I compiled the same using f2py module in python

```
from numpy import f2py

f2py.compile(open('interp.f').read(),modulename='interp',extra_flags='-ffixed-format -ffix-line-length-none',verbose=0)
```

It is unable to compile the module. It gives an error saying invalid file format '' at '-ffized-format'

Please help

Comment: you might try `extra_flags="--opt='-O3 -ffixed-format -ffix-line-length-none'"` (although I do not guarantee this will work).

Comment: sorry i meant extra_flags in my post too. Will give it a shot thanks

Comment: Also, it should be `extra_args` after a quick look at the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `-ffixed-format`, nor `-ffix-line-length-none` seem to be valid gfortran options. Consider using `-ffixed-form` and `-ffixed-line-length-none` instead.